# How do I install more than one WordPress blog on EC2?

Tags: installation

I created an EC2 instance and installed WordPress inside `/var/www/html/blog/`. I'm running Amazon Linux with Apache.

Assuming I want to create another blog. Do I create another directory and install WP as per the first attempt? Or can I run two blogs from the same installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless EC2 is much different than other servers, you should be able to install another WordPress installation under another directory.

For instance, you could have `/var/www/html/blog/` with WordPress installed and `/var/www/html/blog/wordpress` with another WordPress install.

You can either use a separate database or use the same one as the other install, but you would need a unique table prefix set in the wp-config.php.

You can read more about multiple installs here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs

I've never used EC2, but I would assume it would work very similar to any other server. If not, you may want to reach out to their support to see what the differences are.

Comment: Thanks, Jason. I EC2 is just an Amazon Linux AMI. It's pretty much standard fair. What I'm unsure about was if there is a base directory for the install, where all sites go into their own sub-folders. Or whether to just create another folder and unzip the WordPress tar into the new folder, repeating as necessary.

Comment: I use BlueHost often and with them the files are stored under the `public_html` directory. So the root of the site www.yoursite.com is at `public_html`. 

If I create a new directory `public_html/new_site` I can install WordPress there, alongside WordPress at the root. 

So you should be able to create a new directory on your server under the `blogs` directory, and install the new WordPress instance there like you normally would install WordPress.

These will be 2 different sites, essentially.

Comment: The thing you should note though, is that your WP install at the root shouldn't have any permalinks that confilict with your new install. For instance, if you installed the new WP instance at `yoursite.com/wordpress` and you have a page on your main site called `wordpress` when someone visits `yoursite.com/wordpress` it might be an issue. . .